# sublime text 3 html autocompletion not working correctly

Tags: text-editor, sublimetext3

I am trying to use sublimetext3 for editing html.

If I do

`ul` tab, then it generates `<ul></ul>`

if I do 
`ul.temp` tab, then it generates `<ul class="temp"></ul>`

however, when I am trying
`ul>li.temp` tab, it is generating `ul><li class="temp"></li>`

What I am expecting to see is `<ul><li class="temp"></li></ul>`

I have package control. What am I missing in getting this functionality?

Comment: I can guess what you are trying to do, but it is unclear from your question. You state what is happening, but not the desired behavior. Anyways, perhaps the behavior you are looking for comes from the [Emmet](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#readme) plugin

Comment: Thanks.. updated the question and you are right. Write this as answer and I will accept it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note: Moved to an answer at the request of the original poster.*

Perhaps the behavior you are looking for comes from the [Emmet](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#readme) plugin

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing it the expected behavior for Sublime Text.

The functionality that you are looking for comes from [Emmet](http://emmet.io/) as skuroda said. Just install it using Package Control and you should be good to go.